# ical get date from recurring event by RRULE and DTSTART

Tags: python, icalendar, caldav

I need to calculate the next possible date from recurring event. From vcalender I got this information:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20130711T130000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH
```

Using http://pythonhosted.org/caldav/ to get events by date.

```
start_date = datetime.today()
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=7)

calendar.date_search(start_date, end_date)
```

But there is an event for today within this information, is it possible to calculate/print the correct date with this information?

```
y.getChildValue('rrule')
    u'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH'

y.getChildValue('dtstart')
    datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 11, 13, 0, tzinfo=<tzicalvtz 'Europe/Berlin'>)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are willing to use an additional module, give [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) a try, e.g.

```
import dateutil.rrule as rrule
rule = rrule.rrulestr(y.getChildValue('rrule'), dtstart=y.getChildValue('dtstart'))
rule.after(y.getChildValue('dtstart'))
```

should return:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 18, 13, 0)
```

Comment: @Christain Geier: Sorry if i not replayed. Found that solution too, but have to remove the tzinfo <br/>rule = rrule.rrulestr(y.getChildValue('rrule'), dtstart=y.getChildValue('dtstart').replace(tzinfo=None)